# Connection failed: SQLState: '01000' SQL Server Error: 10061

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to connect my access front-end to the SQL Server backend.

It was working when SQL Server was on my computer but now i'm trying to connect to a server

So when I create the DSN file with access

1. I chose SQL-Server driver ( I have also tried with SQL-Server native 10.0 )
2. I enter the server name that I copied from SQL Management Studio so there's no typo there
3. I chose the NT authentication

Then I have this error

[image]

In the properties, I tried with `TCP/IP` with the default port 1433 and I also tried with the name pipes

I made sure that the checkbox to allow remote connection is checked

If I try to connect with management studio I can see the server when I browse on the network but I got this error

[image]

I'm trying [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/07/19/tcp-provider-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it.aspx) troubleshotting but i'm stuck with the telnet command. It says `Could not open connection to host on 1433`

I also tried with no port and i got the same error on port 23

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server Express, remote connections are not allowed by default. Have you enabled them?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012

Comment: After 2 days on this, thank you so much!!! I thought that blank was for the default port which is 1433

Comment: Computers, eh? You know what you know, and there's no shame in asking...